# Symfony 3 can't find my CSS asset file

Tags: html, css, symfony

Symfony can't seem to find my css file, I have looked through many webpages regarding this topic but none of them helped me.

Below is an example of my head:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/theme.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
```

I have absolutely no clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: [Symfony Cache Clear ?](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html)

Comment: Where is your css folder located?

Comment: In the Web folder

Comment: Can you please write the folder structure of the Web Folder. So that we can help you out something better

Comment: The whole path toward my file would be web/css/theme.css

Comment: I fixed the problem myself, but thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put your CSS file under /web/css directory ?

Three possibilities:

```
CTRL + F5
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console assets:install
```

Comment: My file is indeed under the /web/css directory. And I already tried CTRL + F5 :(

Comment: Try the other commands too. I recommand you to use PHPStorm with Symfony and PHPAnnotation plugin installed and you will get autocomplete if your file is under correct folder.

Comment: The commands didn't really work, and I already am using PHPStorm with the plugins you said :D. But I found the problem myself, it had to do with XAMPP's web server not managing to find the file. When I started Symfony's server it worked with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for helping anyway!